# Error Static file referenced by handler not found: dist/api/landing for Angular App deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: html, angular, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

please help, I do not have experience deploying, I have been trying for days, bear with me. Thanks.

I have been working on a angular app with flask backend and both work proper locally, I need to deploy them. The server is written in flask and it is accessible via Postman. The page renders properly from "https://apt-trainer-279210.uc.r.appspot.com/" but on API call an error 404 not found when calling "api/landing" to my server. Going to the logs on GAE I see error.

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: dist/api/landing
```

I am guessing that its looking for file in the above path but it should be calling my server instead. Below is my app.yaml file for angular:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
 - url: /
   static_files: dist/index.html
   upload: dist/index.html
 - url: /
   static_dir: dist

skip_files:
 - e2e/
 - node_modules/
 - src/
 - coverage
 - ^(.*/)?\..*$
 - ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
 - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
 - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
 - ^LICENSE
```

Also note that in the angular app I proxy to the server:

```
 {
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://civil-planet-279210.uc.r.appspot.com" ,
  "secure": true,
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
  "^/api/*": ""
 }
```

}
}

A [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073398/app-yaml-configuration-issue-when-deploying-angular-7-website-and-google-app-eng) was also posted but the user was using Cloud Endpoints while my server is in python flask. I could not use the solution.

Not sure if I should post the app.yaml for the python server as it is working properly.

Your assistance would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the issue with the following yaml -  I was missing the third handler.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: dist

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

skip_files:
- e2e/
- node_modules/
- src/
- coverage
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.json$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
- ^LICENSE
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding this is working as expected. According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) about header element we may find in `url` part:

> The URL pattern has some differences in behavior when used with the following elements:
>
> `static_dir`
>
> Uses a URL prefix. The regular express pattern should not
> contain groupings when used with the static_dir element. All URLs that
> begin with this prefix are handled by this handler, using the portion
> of the URL after the prefix as part of the file path.

So calling `.../api/landing` will use the same logic: " using the portion of the URL after the prefix as part of the file path."

I am not sure what is your intention, but I think you should create the `handler` for the feature you want to invoke.

BTW you are using Python 2 which is not already not recommended and not supported. I would consider migration. You can see this at top of every page of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python).